# XmlDocument Save Throwing Access Denied

Tags: c#, xml, file-io, xmldocument

I'm trying to save an XML string to an XML file. In most cases the XML file will already exist, and I would like to over write it. Currently I'm getting an exception saying that access to the file is denied.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
xDoc.Save(filePath);
```

If I first add this:

```
if(File.Exists(filePath)
{
    File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

then there is no issue. So I'm assuming it just won't let me over write the file? I'd prefer not to delete the file each time.

What is the proper solution here? Should I try to load the file first, and replace all of its contents with my xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing into the xml file

`using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                doc.Save(writer);
                writer.Close();
            }`

Comment: Why would this be any different?

Comment: Same access denied exception.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for you to include the Exception type and message in your question.  If you are receiving an UnauthorizedAccessException, these typically come in two flavors: missing privileges, and concurrent file access.

Since you are able to delete the file via managed file access calls (which I'm assuming you are executing via the same utility and credentials), it might be worth reviewing what processes could be accessing your file while you are attempting to save.  If there is another process opening or writing to that location (including text editors), or if a different process is writing the file with a custom privilege allocation (presumably lacking the "Create Files / Write Data" privilege and including the "Delete Files" privilege), it could cause exceptions of this type.

If your program is the only consumer of this file, and you are only executing one thread at a time, you may want to do a sanity check which permissions your file inherits from the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the file(filePath) exists and it has hidden attributes, XmlDocument.Save() will cause Access Denied to occur.